# F# Debugger in VS Code Polyglot (Interactive) Notbook

Tags: f#, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, f#-interactive, polyglot

Is there an F# debugger extension for use in VS Code Polyglot (formerly Interactive) Notebooks?

I need to see what is happening to my data structures in my Polyglot F# code.  It owuld be great to see their values during runtime.

I've had to give up and return to a VS Pro Console app but would prefer to use VS Code and Polyglot if there is an available F# debugger extension?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No.
"Polyglot Notebooks doesn't currently support the use of a debugger within a notebook"

https://github.com/dotnet/interactive/issues/3446#issuecomment-1938980253